# Can't reach my servers on pgAdmin4

Tags: pgadmin-4

I have an issue on pgAdmin 4.14: I can't open the servers anymore. Whenever I open it I have this never-ending wheel.

[image]

Furthermore, I have this weird pop-up that I can't close.

I was able to reach my servers correctly yesterday.

Comment: Not to be flip but... have you tried turning it off and turning it back on again? Last time this happened to me in pgAdmin 4, a reboot cleared it up ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯